# Renderering problem with flat terrain

Tags: opengl, c++, terrain-rendering

i was testing out my game engine last night, but stumbled across this unexpected result. Here is a picture:
[image]

As it appears, it is renderering 1 triangle and not renderering the other triangles. I believe it is a problem with either the renderer or, least suspecting, the terrain generation. But, on that note it was rendering the some obj models with no problem. i have checked alot of things, E.G the renderer, the model3D class, buffers and the terrain generation code.

Code time!

one of the model3D constructors:

```
            pr_VAO = new buffers::VertexArray();

            pr_VAO->addBuffer(new buffers::Buffer(vertices, sizeof(vertices), 3), 0);
            pr_VAO->addBuffer(new buffers::Buffer(textureCoords, sizeof(textureCoords), 2), 1);
            pr_VAO->addBuffer(new buffers::Buffer(normals, sizeof(normals), 3), 2);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            texture::Texture texture("res/images/grass.png");
            texture.bind();
            shader.setUniform1i("tex", 0);

            pr_IBO = new buffers::IndexBuffer(indices, sizeof(indices));
```

The IndexBuffer constructor:

```
    IndexBuffer::IndexBuffer(GLuint* data, GLsizei count) : pr_Count(count) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &pr_BufferID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pr_BufferID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, count * sizeof(GLuint), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
```

The Buffer class:

```
    Buffer::Buffer(GLfloat* data, GLsizei count, GLuint componentCount) : pr_ComponentCount(componentCount) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &pr_BufferID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pr_BufferID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, count * sizeof(GLfloat), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
```

And finally, the renderer:

```
while (!pr_Models.empty()) {
                const Model3D* model = pr_Models.front();

                model->getVAO()->bind();
                model->getIBO()->bind();

                glm::mat4 matrix;
                glm::translate(matrix, model->getPosition());

                model->getShader().setUniformMat4("ml_matrix", matrix);
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model->getIBO()->getCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

                model->getIBO()->unbind();
                model->getVAO()->unbind();

                pr_Models.pop_front();
            }
```

Thank you very much for your time and understanding

EDIT Sorry forgot to add terrain generation code:

```
int VERTEX_COUNT = 128;
int SIZE = 800;

const int count = 128 * 128;
GLfloat temp_vertices[(count) * 3];
GLfloat temp_normals[(count) * 3];
GLfloat temp_textureCoords[(count) * 2];
GLuint temp_indices[6 * (128 - 1)*(128 * 1)];

int vertexPointer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<VERTEX_COUNT; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<VERTEX_COUNT; j++) {
        temp_vertices[vertexPointer * 3] = (float)j / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        temp_vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 1] = 1.0;
        temp_vertices[vertexPointer * 3 + 2] = (float)i / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        temp_normals[vertexPointer * 3] = 0;
        temp_normals[vertexPointer * 3 + 1] = 1;
        temp_normals[vertexPointer * 3 + 2] = 0;
        temp_textureCoords[vertexPointer * 2] = (float)j / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1);
        temp_textureCoords[vertexPointer * 2 + 1] = (float)i / ((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1);
        vertexPointer++;
    }
}
int pointer = 0;
for (int gz = 0; gz<VERTEX_COUNT - 1; gz++) {
    for (int gx = 0; gx<VERTEX_COUNT - 1; gx++) {
        int topLeft = (gz*VERTEX_COUNT) + gx;
        int topRight = topLeft + 1;
        int bottomLeft = ((gz + 1)*VERTEX_COUNT) + gx;
        int bottomRight = bottomLeft + 1;
        temp_indices[pointer++] = topLeft;
        temp_indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
        temp_indices[pointer++] = topRight;
        temp_indices[pointer++] = topRight;
        temp_indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
        temp_indices[pointer++] = bottomRight;
    }
}
```

EDIT__2: Turns out that models are not working either anymore. i must have accedentally changed something i shouldnt have of.

EDIT__3: sorry managed to get the model rendering working. terrain still not rendering though

Comment: I can't see any of your opengl calls because they are hidden by functions.  I wrote this a while ago if it helps at all: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111875/terrain-shader-from-heightmap-opengl-glsl/111886#111886

Comment: A guess: I had a similar problem a long time ago, make sure your sending the vertex count, not the polygon count to glDrawElements/glDrawArrays.